# Why are some of my extensions or keybindings' when clauses broken in VS Code 1.77's official and insiders releases?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some of the when clauses for my VS Code extensions have stopped working properly in VS Code 1.77 (2023 March)'s official and insiders releases.

I'm observing these breakages in the form of unexpected behaviour of various extension contribution and configuration points that use when clauses, such as when certain contributed commands and UI elements such as menus and views are enabled or disabled, or with my local keboard shortcuts in [my keybindings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules).

Why is this happening, and how can this issue be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code changed the way it parses [When Clauses](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts) in [version 1.77](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_77#_new-when-clause-parser) (the March 2023 version).

This change is described in the announcement and discussion issue ticket here: [Upcoming when clause context parser #175540](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175540). The change added support for parenthesis (for controlling expression precedence), more regular expression support, and `===` and `!==` operators. See [that issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175540) for more information and the exact details of the new grammar.

Possible reasons for breakages of old when clauses with the new grammar include not putting regular expressions between forward-slashes, or incorrect escaping of forward slashes inside regular expressions, string values which contain spaces and are not wrapped with single-quotes, and comparison operators without spaces separating them from their operands.

If you are an extension maintainer, you can use VS Code Insiders, which comes with a linter to detect errors in when clauses in package.json files. Several extension maintainers have been given advance notice that some of their extensions may experience breakage if not adjusted for the new grammar. You can find the list in [that same issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175540).

If you are simply an extension user experiencing such breakages and you have read about the changes and how to migrate the grammar, you can help the issue get resolved by offering Pull Requests to help adjust extensions to the new grammar. Please refrain from pestering your extension maintainers with "me too" comments in issue tickets regarding such issues.